# Ubuntu 15.10 Only plays Audio CDs

Tags: mount, wine

I'm trying to install a copy of (Windows) Quake I have on Ubuntu 15.10 (Unity), and Ubuntu is only mounting the Audio CD part of the disc, I can only play the music from the CD, I have no access to the games installer or anything!

When I tried mount /cdrom:

```
mount: can't find /cdrom in /etc/fstab
```

When I try mount /dev/sr0:

```
mount: mount point /mnt/cdrom does not exist
```

So what do I do?

Comment: What do you mean it is only mounting the audio portion? The audio portion is not something that can be mounted. When I place my Quake CD into my bluray drive, there are two icons which show up on the launcher bar, one for _Audio Disc_, and one for _QUAKE101_. That is on 14.04, but this functionality hasn't been changed in a long time.

Comment: @dobey Well, it's only the Audio Disc icon that shows up, the Quake one doesn't...

Comment: In Nautilus (file manager) too?

Comment: @dobey Yep, there too, going into "media/*my username*", The CD doesn't appear... http://i.imgur.com/HNoyLyd.png

Comment: I have tried some other games, and I can confirm that it does the exact same thing with them as well, and the ones that don't have redbook audio, don't show the CD mounted at all...

Comment: OK. This sounds like a bug then. I'd suggest reporting the problem at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+filebug so that it's recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this may help: "5.9 The application's CD or DVD looks empty or is missing some files!" https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ

Comment: All of the suggestions there just remount the audio part of the disc, but I think we're getting somewhere now...

Comment: I found a solution with the help of your link! I entered in a terminal
`sudo mkdir /media/cdrom0`
and then:
`sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro,unhide /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom0`
and it worked!